# irt hybrid model predict latent estimate using bayesian method

Tags: maximum-likelihood, predictive-models, stata, latent-variable, item-response-theory

I'm having some problem about irt prediction model.

When i use irt hybrid model, it cannot predict the latent value even it has successfully converge during the irt model processed.

It contain binary variable and ordinal variable.

global pvars1 = "varA" global pvars2 = "varB"

set seed 2453

IRT model

irt hybrid (2pl $pvars1) (grm $pvars2) estat report $pvars1 $pvars2, byparm sort(b) predict latent_hybird, latent se(latent_se_hybird)

[image]

predict latent_hybird, latent se(latent_se_hybird)

*(option ebmeans assumed) (using 7 quadrature points) could not compute empirical Bayes means; missing values were returned by the evaluator*

any clues about this problem?

thank you so much